# Python Scripting for Photoshop - resizeImage not working as expected

Tags: python, photoshop

I'm trying to perform a simple operation.  Resizing an image I have loaded up in photoshop.

This is my code

```
    psApp.Open(psdFiles[0])  # Opens the PSD
    awayActiveDoc = psApp.Application.ActiveDocument  # Get active document object

    #Set units to pixels.
    psApp.Preferences.RulerUnits = 1

    #Printing out a bunch of info for the loaded doc.
    print "\n Active document:", awayActiveDoc.name
    print " Initial Doc size:", int(awayActiveDoc.width), int(awayActiveDoc.height)
    print " Doc path:", awayActiveDoc.path
    print " Doc BitsPerChannel:", awayActiveDoc.BitsPerChannel

    awayActiveDoc.Flatten()
    awayActiveDoc.resizeImage("51%", "51%")
```

And this is the illegal operation I'm getting when attempting to resize the image.  Any ideas?

> File "e:\py_projects\py_crowd\test2.py", line 73, in 
>     awayActiveDoc.resizeImage("51%", "51%")
>   File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 511, in **getattr**
>     ret = self.*oleobj*.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
>
> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Adobe >Photoshop', u'Illegal Argument', None, 0, -2147024809), None)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a syntax error.

```
awayActiveDoc.resizeImage("51%", "51%")
```

needed to be

```
awayActiveDoc.ResizeImage("51%", "51%")
```

with a capital `R`.